# C++ Получить уникальные ID/серийники железа

Tags: c++

Всем привет. В С++ нужно получить серийники как минимум ещё 1-2 железяк, серийник тома жестака я уже получил через этот код:

```
unsigned long drive_sn;
unsigned int drive_type = GetDriveType(NULL);

char VolumeNameBuffer[100];
char FileSystemNameBuffer[100];
LPDWORD sz = NULL, fs = NULL;
GetVolumeInformationA(NULL, VolumeNameBuffer, 100, &drive_sn, sz, fs, FileSystemNameBuffer, 100);
```

Теперь мне нужно получить ещё 1-2 подобных серийника, например видео карты, материнки или чего угодно, что не меняется, пока не вынешь ее из компа (или не изменишь программно)
**Заранее спасибо.**
Мне бы желательно готовый пример, так как в C++ я новичок

Comment: Посмотрите WMI.